# Kotlin - Coroutine not executing as expected

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, program-entry-point, coroutine, kotlin-flow

This couldn't be any simpler but I'm unable to understand what is the issue here. Here is my code:

```
fun main() {

    val flow = flowOf(1, 2, 3)

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        println("Launch working")
        flow.collect {
            println("Collect: $it")
        }
    }
}
```

The above code prints nothing, not even "Launch working". I even tried using my own `CoroutineScope`, like in the following code:

```
fun main() {

    val flow = flowOf(1, 2, 3)

    val myCoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(
        CoroutineName("myCoroutineScope")
    )

    myCoroutineScope.launch {
        println("My coroutine scope working")
        flow.collect {
            println("Collect: $it")
        }
    }
}
```

Again, it printed nothing, not even "My coroutine scope working".

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use `runBlocking` and `Job.join()` to wait for the coroutine to finish:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {

    val flow = flowOf(1, 2, 3)

    val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        println("Launch working")
        flow.collect {
            println("Collect: $it")
        }
    }
    job.join()
}
```

It will block the execution of the `main()` function until the `flow` is collected.

Comment: Alright, that's what I was missing. The program was ending before anything inside coroutines could be executed.